# how to set (numlock and capslock) for turning on logitech script

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

hello everyone I want to use "capslock" off or on instead of buttons 4 and 5 to change the first and second code and use "numlock" to activate and deactivate the script, if anyone can please help me this is my script:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
      ReleaseMouseButton(2) -- to prevent it from being stuck on
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and (arg == 4 or arg == 5) then     
      recoil = recoil ~= arg and arg
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoil == 4 then
      repeat
         MoveMouseRelative(-2, 3)
         Sleep(10)
         MoveMouseRelative(2, -2)
         Sleep(10)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoil == 5 then
      repeat 
    MoveMouseRelative(-10, 9)
    Sleep(16)
    MoveMouseRelative(10, -10)
    Sleep(16)
   until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) 
   end
end
```

i want to set numlock to turn on and off script. and i want to set when capslock is off script use this:

```
repeat
     MoveMouseRelative(-2, 3)
     Sleep(10)
     MoveMouseRelative(2, -2)
     Sleep(10)
until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
```

and when capslock is on script use
this:

```
repeat 
    MoveMouseRelative(-10, 9)
    Sleep(16)
    MoveMouseRelative(10, -10)
    Sleep(16)
until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
```

plz help me if you can . thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the current status of lock-keys by invoking function `IsKeyLockOn`:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) and IsKeyLockOn"numlock" then
      if not IsKeyLockOn"capslock" then
         -- capslock is off 
         repeat
            MoveMouseRelative(-2, 3)
            Sleep(10)
            MoveMouseRelative(2, -2)
            Sleep(10)
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
      else
         -- capslock is on
         repeat 
            MoveMouseRelative(-10, 9)
            Sleep(16)
            MoveMouseRelative(10, -10)
            Sleep(16)
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) 
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: how can i add the line:  if (IsMouseButtonPressed(3) and IsMouseButtonPressed(1)) then 
repeat

Comment: Answer updated.